# How to insert a video intro & outtro with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, join

I have a video long time, i want to insert a video intro & outtro ? how can I do this?

```
ffmpeg -i intro -i mainvideo -i outtro outputvideo
```

Comment: Just look at the documentation:
[https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec)

Answer (score 0):

Use concat

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i intro -i mainvideo -i outro output.mov
```

Another way is to use a text file with one video per line like this:

```
file '/path/to/intro'
file '/path/to/main_video'
file '/path/to/outro'
```

You can save it as video_filelist.txt and then issue a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i '/path/to/video_filelist.txt' output.mov
```

You can read more about concat [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Comment: The first command is wrong. The concat demuxer only accepts a textfile as input.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Mulvya. You're right. To concat from the command line without relying on any external text file, you'd have to use the [concat](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter.